# Correlated Subquery to find AVG of certain groups

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

Question! I'm trying to list all books and their corresponding book subject, average cost and regular cost.

So far my query is...

```
SELECT BOOK_SUBJECT, AVG( BOOK_COST ) 
FROM BOOK 
GROUP BY BOOK_SUBJECT
```

This query gives me the avg of the four groups total cost. [Final out put should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amKce.jpg) I need to bring in `BOOK_NUM`, `BOOK_TITLE`, `BOOK_SUBJECT`, `BOOK_COST`, but I'm unable to figure it out.  Can someone help?  Correlated subquery?

Comment: Are you using SQL-Server, MySQL, or something else?  Please add a tag for what you are using, but not the others.

Comment: You should also include the full structure of the book table (and any other tables it joins to). Otherwise the answers will be pure speculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT BOOK_NUM AS Number,
       BOOK_TITLE AS Title,
       BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT AS Subject,
       BOOK_COST AS Cost,
       AVG_BOOK_COST AS 'Avg Cost'
FROM BOOK
JOIN ( SELECT BOOK_SUBJECT AS BOOK_SUBJECT,
              AVG( BOOK_COST ) AS AVG_BOOK_COST
       FROM BOOK
       GROUP BY BOOK_SUBJECT
     ) AS SUBJECT_AVG_FINDER ON BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT = SUBJECT_AVG_FINDER.BOOK_SUBJECT
ORDER BY BOOK_NUM;
```

To calculate the average for each Subject we have to group the contents of `BOOK` by `BOOK_SUBJECT` and use `AVG( BOOK_COST )` to find the mean average for each group.  But we also wish to avoid grouping the other fields in `BOOK`, instead having the specified fields from each record in Book displayed with their `BOOK_SUBJECT`'s average cost tacked on the end.  This suggests that an `INNER JOIN` between `BOOK` and a subquery that is used to find the mean average of cost for each subject.

I used the following code to find the mean average cost for each subject listed in `BOOK`...

```
SELECT BOOK_SUBJECT AS BOOK_SUBJECT,
       AVG( BOOK_COST ) AS AVG_BOOK_COST
FROM BOOK
GROUP BY BOOK_SUBJECT
```

We need to select `BOOK_SUBJECT` partly because the `GROUP BY` clause requires it and partly because we will need it to join the table generated by this subquery to the ungrouped listing of `BOOK`.

Giving `AVG( BOOK_COST )` the alias of `AVG_BOOK_COST` makes referring to this generated field much easier.

In the absence of a join type before the word `JOIN` most versions of SQL will assume an `INNER JOIN`,  although all allow `INNER JOIN` to be used and some require you to do so.  By default I and many others simply use `JOIN`.

Once the join is performed each record from from `BOOK` will have a copy of it's corresponding record from our subquery (which I have given an alias of `SUBJECT_AVG_FINDER`), leaving each record with two fields called `BOOK_SUBJECT`.  So as not to confuse your version of SQL, we must specify the table / subquery along with the field name where such duplication occurs, hence `BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT` in the third line of the overall statement.

Each field has been given an alias as per your desired final output image.

I have assumed that there is no need to replicate the row number field.  If that is incorrect, then please state otherwise.

Finally, I have sorted the results as per your desired output by adding the line `ORDER BY BOOK_NUM`.

As a tip, although it's allowed, you should avoid using shouting (i.e. full uppercase) your field names, table names, and alias' (unless you are required to do so), but still shout the SQL stuff (like `SELECT`, `FROM`, `AS`, etc.).  This can make a statement easier to read and debug by providing a visual clue as to how you are trying to use each word.  I suggest the following way of presenting our SQL statement instead...

```
SELECT book_num AS Number,
       book_title AS Title,
       book.book_subject AS Subject,
       book_cost AS Cost,
       avg_book_cost AS 'Avg Cost'
FROM book
JOIN ( SELECT book_subject AS book_subject,
              AVG( book_cost ) AS avg_book_cost
       FROM book
       GROUP BY book_subject
     ) AS subject_avg_finder ON book.book_subject = subject_avg_finder.book_subject
ORDER BY book_num;
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to do this:

```
SELECT BOOK.BOOK_NUM, BOOK.BOOK_TITLE, BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT, BOOK.BOOK_COST, T.AVG_COST
FROM BOOK
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT BOOK_SUBJECT, AVG(BOOK_COST) AVG_COST
    FROM BOOK
    GROUP BY BOOK_SUBJECT
) T ON BOOK.BOOK_SUBJECT = T.BOOK_SUBJECT
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
SELECT BOOK_NUM, BOOK_TITLE, BOOK_SUBJECT, BOOK_COST,  
AVG(BOOK_COST) OVER(PARTITION BY BOOK_SUBJECT) AS AVG_COST  
FROM BOOK
```